# Disable cache while running SQL - Google Big Query

Tags: sql, caching, google-bigquery, talend

Need some advice on cache issue we are facing in Google Big Query.

I'm using Talend tBigQueryInput component to run a Google Big Query SQL. However the SQL is not returning current data. We are suspecting it is returning stale data from cache.

Is there a disable cache option which can be embeded with in the SQL so that we are saying Big Query strictly not to take from cache?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a disable cache option which can be embeded with in the SQL

No! There is no such option to be used within the query

Meantime, to enforce not using cache you can add something like below to your query

```
WHERE RAND() < 2
```

This is just silly example - but you should get an idea :o)

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for your response. Can you please explain how using something like RAND() < 2 will force the query not to use cache results?

Comment: query result cache is valid for 24 hours and is used if underlying data is not changed, query itself is not changed and result is deterministic. by using non-deterministic function you effectively will force bq engine to not to use cached result - see more about [Exceptions to query caching](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#cache-exceptions)

Comment: ... and obviously because RAND() is always less than 1 it will not affect result of your query :o)

Comment: did this explained? make sense?

Comment: Hi Mikhail, yes this makes sense now. Let me add this condition to SQL and monitor the query for a while. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Two quick thoughts come to mind:

- You could examine the job history in the UI to see the jobs that Talend is running.  From the statistics, they will report whether or not the results were served from cache.  You could also examine the audit logs for this information.
- You could execute an altered test query leveraging a non-deterministic aspect, which will ensure the results cannot be served from cache.  Functions like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, `CURRENT_DATE()` etc should be sufficient for this purpose.

From scanning the public Talend docs, there's no configuration setting I can see that maps into setting `configuration.query.useQueryCache` to false for the query job, which is the behavior you're requesting.

Comment: Hi Shollyman, thanks for your response. For point 1, could you please show where in UI will I be able to see the statistics about results served from cache? In Google Big Query--> Job History . There is no job history for the job run via Talend. Also for the jobs available there, there is no where it says if data is from cache. Also from where can I get the audit logs information. Thanks a lot for your help on this.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  By UI I meant the BigQuery web UI, not a Talend interface, which expose job history information.  If you're using the interface in cloud console, the Query History link in the left nav will expose queries run in a project.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs has more information about BigQuery's audit log functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create UDF([User Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)).

Without UDF execution, there is no query caching via BigQuery WebUI.

e.g.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  FOO_BAR() AS (CONCAT('FOO', 'BAR'));

<Your Uncached Query>
```